# Getting number of characters through it's memory size in python

Tags: python, string-length, smtplib

[ Python ]

I have a string and I know it's size in memory. I want to get the number of characters (a rough estimate) will it contain.

Actual case, I want to send a report through mail, the content of the mail is exceeding the permitted size is allowed for it. I want to split the mail into multiple according to maximum size. But I don't have a way to co-relate the maximum size to number of characters in the string.

```
import smtplib

smtp = smtplib.SMTP('server.name')
smtp.ehlo()
max_size = smtp.esmtp_features['size']

message_data = <some string data exceeding the max_size>
# Now, how can I get the number of characters in message_data which exceeds the max_szie
```

Thanks,

Comment: If its a string, `len(message_data)` will give you a character  count. If its a unicode string you still need to know its size when its encoded. If that's an issue, you could pick your favorite enocoding and try it. `encoded = message_data.encode('utf-8')`. Then its `len(encoded)`.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply, but how would I know how many chars. weigh equal to max size. 2 ** n (n = no. of chars.),  would be a good expression to go with?

Comment: I don't understand... `len(message_data)` is the number of characters in the string. `2**n` grows rather quickly so I don't see how that applies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of chars in a string is the size in memory in bytes to which you must deduct 37 (python 2.7 / mac os)

```
import sys

def estimate_chars():
    "size in bytes"
    s = ""
    for idx in range(100):
        print idx * 10, sys.getsizeof(s), len(s)
        s += '1234567890'

estimate_chars()
```

### result: (chars | bytes | len)

```
0 37 0
10 47 10
20 57 20
30 67 30
40 77 40
50 87 50
...
960 997 960
970 1007 970
980 1017 980
990 1027 990
```

Comment: The number of characters in a string is `len(some_string)`. This seems a round-about way of using an implementation detail to calculate something that already has a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes, indeed, you are entirely correct; I went that way because my first thought was that the OPs text was not in memory and the number of characters needed to be estimated from its known byte size.

Comment: Thanks ReblochonMasque and tdelaney